# Why is Kotlin not sorting the first element of my array?

Tags: kotlin

Maybe I'm missing something here, but it seems like sort isn't sorting the array completely.

This is what I tried:

```
$ kotlinc
Welcome to Kotlin version 1.2.71 (JRE 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.2)
Type :help for help, :quit for quit
>>> var test: String = "This is a test of the user system."
>>> var testarray2: Array<String> = test.split(" ").toTypedArray()
>>> testarray2.sort()
>>> testarray2.forEach { println("${it} ") }
This 
a 
is 
of 
system. 
test 
the 
user 
>>>
```

As you can see, sorting doesn't seem to be sorting the string "This."

I tried installing openjdk-11 and updating all my packages, but I'm still getting this, and I checked that 1.2.71 is the latest Kotlin package.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you do the sorting like this:

```
testarray2.sortBy { it.toLowerCase() }
```

it will be sorted as you wanted it.  
The `sort()` method compares the strings using the ASCII codes of the characters and all uppercase characters have ASCII codes less than the lower case ones so you got the result that seemed to you wrong.  
On the other hand `it.toLowerCase()` will transform all strings to lower case before the sorting so you have case insensitive sorting.

Comment: Yea I just realized that. That was a dumb waste of time. Thank you for your help.